# How to web scraping Highcharts values?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, highcharts

I'm trying to get data from a Highchart, but I only have a "None" value.

The chart needs a password to be accessed, but I have the same problem with the chart on [this page](https://www.worldweatheronline.com/v2/weather-averages.aspx?locid=194044&root_id=192045&wc=local_weather&map=~/brussels-weather-averages/be.aspx).

Using the browser's DevTools I can get the y value from highchart using:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].y
```

Thus, combining this code with a loop structure I can have all the y values.

The problem is when I try to use Selenium to webscraping those values. I'm using the code below

```
page.execute_script('Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].y')
```

The answer I expect is 2 (as in DevTools), but instead I'm getting "None" as answer.

I already tried to use Beautifulsoup to retrieve the y value from the `<path>` tag, but it doesn't meet the expected value.

The HTML source seems to be complex (I'm not expert in these area). The full xpath of the `<svg>` is:
`/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/svg`

Also, I can't find any `<iframe>`, which could be avoiding me from accessing the graph.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? (I'm beginner in this area, so let me know if any further information is necessary)

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: I updated with some information. I don't have any error, I just can't get the correct value. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @fellipe sola, The data is loaded asynchronously, so maybe you call your code too early?

Comment: Hi @user4157124.. unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Apparently the data comes from a js script, therefore, to use this method, I need to create an event to load this script (this is my guess).

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek.. Even with a wait event I can't get the data.

Answer (score 2):

After a long time stuck in it, I figured out how to solve this problem.

My mistake is that I was sending to my browser, via selenium, the js script below to be executed.

```
page.execute_script('Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].y')
```

This code is working perfectly but it doesn't return to me any value. So, in order to have the y value (that is what I need), I just need to use a "return" in the previously code. The final code is

```
page.execute_script('return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data[0].y')
```